# How can I limit access to a virtual host (subdomain) to a few specific IPs?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

The catch is that this virtual host points to the same root location as the main site. It is meant to just mirror the content of www.mysite.com on sub.mysite.com. This prohibits me from using allow and deny rules in my .htaccess, since that would affect www.mysite.com traffic as well. I've also tried using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.55\.76\.234$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.54\.67\.87$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mysite.com [R=301]
```

The IP addresses don't fall into a range, so I think generating a single-line REGEX to cover all of them wouldn't work, and using a series of conditionals like the above simply didn't work, and seemed very messy. The above IPs are just examples. I would need to limit access to roughly 10 unique IPs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to define allow and deny in the virtualhost under the directory node. That should only take effect on the virtualhost you want to.

```
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.55:8080>
    ServerName sub.mysite.com
      <Directory proxy:>
          Order Deny,Allow
          Deny from all
          Allow from 111.22.33
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: is the 'proxy:' portion required? I am not very familiar with mod_proxy.

Comment: you can also fill in your normal directory name like "httpdocs" or just "/".